# Does the lumberjack in Clash Royale do anything special against the log?

Tags: clash-royale

I've always wondered this and watched many many games trying to see it happen, but I've yet to see evidence of it.

Does the lumberjack do anything special if it meets an opponent's log mid-roll? Is he supposed to? The flavor text on the lumberjack card seems to indicate that it does, and it would certainly make sense. It says "He chops trees by day and hunts The Log by night." The Log is even capitalized as if to refer specifically to the legendary card The Log.

However, I've never seen any evidence that it does. When the lumberjack first came out, it seemed like the only reason to even use him, aside from the rage effect when he dies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading through some Supercell forum posts the Lumberjack does not have any sort of special interaction with the Log and the Clash Royale wiki also supports this. However the Lumberjack did create the Log.

Taken from the Wiki: http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Lumberjack

> The Lumberjack seems responsible for creating The Log. The Log turned villainous when a bottle of Rage was spilled on it, much like the one the Lumberjack drinks. This is proven from his description and one of the loading screen tips, saying "The Lumberjack and the Log go way back."

Just a kind of fun fact.